# Deleting a locked page in Plone

Tags: plone

I'm a Plone newbie.  Just installed Plone 4 and the Iterate plugin as it suggested on my first login.  Logged in as admin, I created a folder, then created two pages within it.  Well, I meant one of the pages to be a folder instead of a page, so I tried to delete the page, and it says, `These items are locked for editing: /Plone/my-new-folder/my-accidental-page`.  It was marked as Private so I tried publishing it, and still could not delete it.  I'm the only one logged in and have only one tab open.  How is it locked for editing?  How do I unlock it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log out and log back in as someone else.  Don't ask me why this worked.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the locked item, and you'll see a message telling you that "This item has been locked by  for editing for X hours Y minutes..."  In that message, there will be a button for 'unlock'.  Click that button and you're good to go.